# What does migrate data on TDD mean?

Tags: tdd

I have been reading [Test Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) for a couple weeks. Right now, I stuck on chapter 31 - Refactoring. My question is about Migrate Data on page 183. I don't understand this topic. The example about `TestSuite` doesn't help me understand this too.

I want to know what does migrate data mean and how to use it in TDD.

---

**[Update]** *content from the book*
**Migrate Data**

How do you move from one representation? Temporarily duplicate the data.

*How:*
Here is the internal-to-external version, where you change the representation internally
and then change the externally visible interface:

- Add an instance variable in the new format
- Set the new format variable everywhere you set the old format
- Use the new format variable everywhere you use the old format
- Delete the old format
- Change the external interface to reflect the new format

Sometimes, though, you want to change the API first. Then you should:
 - Add a parameter in the new format
 - Translate from the new format parameter to the old format internal representation
 - Delete the old format parameter
 - Replace uses of the old format with the new format
 - Delete the old format

*Why:*
One to Many creates a data migration problem every time. Suppose we wanted to
implement TestSuite using One to Many. We would start with:

```
def testSuite(self):
suite= TestSuite()
suite.add(WasRun("testMethod"))
suite.run(self.result)
assert("1 run, 0 failed" == self.result.summary())
```

Which is implemented (in the “One” part of One to Many) by:

```
class TestSuite:
def add(self, test):
self.test= test
def run(self, result):
self.test.run(result)
```

Now we begin duplicating data. First we initialize the collection of tests:

```
TestSuite
def __init__(self):
self.tests= []
Everywhere “test” is set, we add to the collection, too:
TestSuite
def add(self, test):
self.test= test
self.tests.append(test)
```

Now we use the list of tests instead of the single test. For purposes of the current
test cases this is a refactoring (it preserves semantics) because there is only ever one
element in the collection.

```
TestSuite
def run(self, result):
for test in self.tests:
test.run(result)
```

We delete the now-unused instance variable “test”:

```
TestSuite
def add(self, test):
self.tests.append(test)
```

You can also use stepwise data migration when moving between equivalent formats
with different protocols, as in moving from Java’s Vector/Enumerator to Collection/
Iterator.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context on the question. I don't have a copy, so it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: I just added content from the book to the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a refactoring where you want to change the way that the data is represented.

As the book says, *an* example is moving from One to Many e.g. you have made a scenario work for one Test, now you want to improve that to handle N Tests. So now you would have to change (migrate) the data representation say from a Test instance variable to a `List<Test>`. Making this change can be done incrementally in an inside-out or an outside-in approach

- Outside in (preferred) - Add an extra parameter to the existing APIs in the new representation (e.g. you change a param from primitive to a custom structure). Make all clients compile. Rewire the internals of the APIs to use the new param where the old is used (another option is to duplicate so that you have both being used temporarily). Soon your IDE should show you that the old (primitive) param is no longer in use. At that moment, you can safely delete that param. The idea is to preserve the behavior of the code, all through the refactoring.